# Pfquery...object to array.. to label

Tags: nsmutablearray, parse-platform, pfquery

it is my first time that I use parse and I'm a beginner.

I have built a table, and I show in the rows the data of my array

```
myArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pasquale", @"Mario", nil];
```

cell.label1.text=  [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Now I want to fetch the data from a class in parse and I wrote:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Dispositivi"];
[query whereKey:@"NomeDispositivo" equalTo:@"Franco"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
// The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
}
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

The code worked. But I want to know : How I can put the object in the array...and I can put a row in the array. For example every String of row: Name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the array:

```
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
```

*instead of your `for` loop. Note that this would currently result in your array containing `NSString` and `PFObject` instances and that could cause you issues...

Alternatively, replace the existing array:

```
myArray = [objects mutableCopy];
```